# combobox.selected value can't pass to query

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have the following query.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT RoomNo, RoomBedsNo, RoomSmoking, RoomMiniBar,RoomKitchen,RoomFirePlace,RoomBalcony, RoomVeranda, RoomGarden, RoomEntrance, RoomAirCondition, RoomTV FROM tblrooms WHERE FK_roomTypesID = '" + cboRoomType.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
```

And the problem is that though the `cboRoomType.SelectedValue`, near the `WHERE` is 1. I can't get the value and fill my `datagrid`. There is no error, just nothing to return from the database.

The following code works perfect.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT RoomNo, RoomBedsNo, RoomSmoking, RoomMiniBar,RoomKitchen,RoomFirePlace,RoomBalcony, RoomVeranda, RoomGarden, RoomEntrance, RoomAirCondition, RoomTV FROM tblrooms WHERE FK_roomTypesID = '1'", conn);
```

What's wrong with that? I don't know if I have to provide more infos.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Inspect the value of `cmboRoomType` and ensure it has a valid integer value.

Comment: I have already check that and it is a valid integer value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedValue returns an object, you must cast it to an integer.